# Display Excel values in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue with filling a `DataGridView` from an Excel file that is online. On button click, the app should create a new tab, add a `DataGridView` and populate with values from the Excel file. How can I do it?

Here is what I did so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim tempTabExist = False

    Private Sub SiteList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SiteList.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim wkbTemplRaspored As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        If tempTabExist = False Then
            Call CreateNewTabPage()
        End If
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True
        wkbTemplRaspored = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("http://CRNO/RAN/Raspored%20R%20A%20N_v1.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = wkbTemplRaspored.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateNewTabPage()

        Dim tp As New TabPage

        tempTabExist = True
        tp.Name = "SiteList"
        tp.Text = "SiteList"

        Call CreateNewGrid(tp)

        Me.TabControl.TabPages.Add(tp)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateNewGrid(ByRef TP As TabPage)

        Dim dg As New DataGridView

        dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        dg.Name = "Raspored"

        dg.Columns.Add(dg.Name, "Site Name")
        dg.Columns.Add(dg.Name, "Technology")
        dg.Columns.Add(dg.Name, "Week")
        dg.Columns.Add(dg.Name, "Engineer")
        TP.Controls.Add(dg)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Most* of your code seems to be working. I would change a few things however apart from listing the data in your `DataGridView` the code does appear to work.

To retrieve data from `Excel` and view in a `DataGridView` I would look at the following code:

```
Using con As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Test.xlsx'; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;';"),
      com As Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()

    con.Open()

    Dim dtSheetName As DataTable
    dtSheetName = con.GetSchema("Tables")

    If dtSheetName.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        com.CommandText = "select * from [" & dtSheetName.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString() & "]"
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        dtRows.Load(com.ExecuteReader())

    End If

End Using
```

There are bits of code here you may need to change as I haven't tested with your `Data Source`. Instead I used my own.

I would look at changing your method `CreateNewTabPage` slightly to return a `TabPage`:

```
Private Function CreateNewTabPage() As TabPage

    Dim tp As New TabPage

    tp.Name = "SiteList"
    tp.Text = "SiteList"

    Return tp

End Function
```

Instead of calling `CreateNewGrid` from `CreateNewTabPage` I would do this on your button click. I would however pass through the `DataTable` as well as the `TabPage`.

Additionally since we are assigning a `DataTable` as the `DataSource` we don't need to add columns manually. Here is what I would do:

```
Private Sub CreateNewGrid(ByRef TP As TabPage,
                          ByVal dt As DataTable)

    Dim dg As New DataGridView

    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    dg.Name = "Raspored"

    dg.DataSource = dt

    TP.Controls.Add(dg)

End Sub
```

This is how I would call both methods:

```
If dtRows.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim tabPage As TabPage = CreateNewTabPage()

    If tabPage IsNot Nothing Then
        If TabControl1.TabPages.ContainsKey(tabPage.Name) Then
            TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(tabPage.Name)
        End If

        CreateNewGrid(tabPage, dtRows)
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
    End If
End If
```

Notice that I check for the tab and should it exist, I remove it. You may want to do something similar.

All together your code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub SiteList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SiteList.Click

    Dim dtRows As New DataTable

    Using con As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='http://CRNO/RAN/Raspored%20R%20A%20N_v1.xlsx'; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;';"),
          com As Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()

        con.Open()

        Dim dtSheetName As DataTable
        dtSheetName = con.GetSchema("Tables")

        If dtSheetName.Rows.Count > 0 Then

            com.CommandText = "select * from [" & dtSheetName.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString() & "]"
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            dtRows.Load(com.ExecuteReader())

        End If

    End Using

    If dtRows.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim tabPage As TabPage = CreateNewTabPage()

        If tabPage IsNot Nothing Then
            If TabControl1.TabPages.ContainsKey(tabPage.Name) Then
                TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(tabPage.Name)
            End If

            CreateNewGrid(tabPage, dtRows)
            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Function CreateNewTabPage() As TabPage

    Dim tp As New TabPage

    tp.Name = "SiteList"
    tp.Text = "SiteList"

    Return tp

End Function

Private Sub CreateNewGrid(ByRef TP As TabPage,
                          ByVal dt As DataTable)

    Dim dg As New DataGridView

    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    dg.Name = "Raspored"

    dg.DataSource = dt

    TP.Controls.Add(dg)

End Sub
```

<sup>If you haven't already you may need to download [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  Here are two ideas for you to muse over.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Book1.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Also, try this.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Data.OleDb

'~~> Define your Excel Objects


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        'Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        'Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Dim strConn As String
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dao_dbE As dao.DBEngine
        Dim dao_DB As DAO.Database
        Dim strFirstSheetName As String

        dao_dbE = New dao.DBEngine
        dao_DB = dao_dbE.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\DOT.NET\Samples VB\Import into DataGrid from Excel & Export from DataGrid to Excel #2\Book3.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;")
        strFirstSheetName = dao_DB.TableDefs(0).Name
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\DOT.NET\Samples VB\Import into DataGrid from Excel & Export from DataGrid to Excel #2\Book3.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & _
        strFirstSheetName & "]", strConn)
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Excel")
        da.Fill(ds)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

        da.Dispose()
        dao_DB.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```